# C#: Why does it take so long to get a Task t.Result when the task has already finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm wondering why it takes so long to get results from already finished tasks.

```
List<Task<T>> myTasks = someList.Select(x => Task.Run(() => DoSomethingWith(x)));
Task.WaitAll(myTasks.ToArray());
var myResults = myTasks.Select(task => task.Result); // the line that takes too long
```

Timing these individual lines shows that a significant amount of time is spent in the last line (more than 25ms for 10 tasks). In my mind, getting the result should be something that is almost instantaneous as the result should already exist at that time. Is there a better way to get the results in this kind of situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is await async so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665635/why-is-await-async-so-slow)

Comment: It should return them instantaneously if they are finished (RanToCompletion).

Comment: @trailmax What does this question has to do with async/await?

Comment: @trailmax The line in question is not using await..?

Comment: @RufusL It is all about parallelization, this linked question has some good answers showing why you see what you see.

Comment: Internally `.Result` returns result from a private field if the task is finished (RanToCompletion). Because you wait for them with `Task.WaitAll`, they all are in `RanToCompletion` state. I would say this is more of an issue with benchmarking. ~25 ms is not that much maybe you benchmark this incorrectly.

Comment: Can you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The code you've provided wouldn't even compile, and when I try modifying it to compile I'm unable to produce the results you're describing. (I'm seeing ~1 ms for ten results on the first run, and <0.001 ms for subsequent runs.)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Yes, I will try to do that.

Comment: **Use a profiler to diagnose performance problems**. That 25 ms has to be attributed to something; what is it?

Comment: That line of code doesn't even *get* the `Result`s.

Comment: @trailmax Is there any parallelization happening after calling `.WaitAll`?

Comment: FCin and Rufus L: Even though the question doesn't deal with async/await, many of the points in the accepted answer probably apply here (dealing with mistakes made in benchmarking with so few data points, etc.)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Ah, yes, now *that* makes sense, it most likely has to do with the benchmarking code. Voted to close since this doesn't include the benchmarking code and isn't even the code that reproduces the problem (`Select` does not return a `List`)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll update this as you update your question, but here's my best guess.

This line doesn't compile, because Select doesn't return a List:

```
List<Task<T>> myTasks = someList.Select(x => Task.Run(() => DoSomethingWith(x)));
```

I'm going to hazard a guess that you're actually doing this:

```
var myTasks = someList.Select(x => Task.Run(() => DoSomethingWith(x)));
```

... which produces a cold `IEnumerable`: one which will only run when it actually gets iterated over.

In the code above, you're iterating over it when you call `.ToArray()` on it. But the line you describe as taking 25ms is likewise producing nothing but another cold `IEnumerable<>`. No real work is being done here:

```
var myResults = myTasks.Select(task => task.Result);
```

So again I'm going to hazard a guess that you're doing something more like this:

```
var myResults = myTasks.Select(task => task.Result).ToList();
```

... which is going to iterate over `myTasks` *a second time*, causing `Task.Run(...)` to get called again for each item in `someList`, and then waiting for all of those tasks to complete.

In other words, you're doing the work twice, and one of those times in in the line that you reference at the end.

Fortunately, there is a better way to do what you're doing, using the Task Parallel Library.

```
var myResults = someList
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(x => DoSomethingWith(x))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: But when you try to get a `.Result` on already completed task then it is going to return a result from stored field instead of doing the same work multiple times. You can iterate over a list of finished tasks as many times as you want without running them.

Comment: Yes, this was it. Somehow, I thought I was safe as I used a .ToArray() but I totally missed this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FCin: If he was working with a *List* of finished tasks, you'd be absolutely right. My conjecture (which it sounds like was accurate) is that he had an *IEnumerable* which knew *how to create Tasks* when you iterate over it. Since it got iterated over twice, the `.Result` was being invoked on a new set of tasks which had not yet completed.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Ahh ok, It seems that you are right. I created example to confirm this: http://rextester.com/RJYY87730

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that the 3rd line is the one that is causing the slowdown, then there is little to do. This is all runtime library code, and MS runs a pretty tight ship when it comes to optimization.

You may want to iterate over your myTasks manually to avoid the Select code, but I'd be surprised if you gained even a few milliseconds.

Comment: This should be a comment, as it doesn't answer the question.