# Why did my async with ContinueWith deadlock?

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, deadlock, dapper

**I'm not after a solution here, more an explanation of what's going on.** I've refactored this code to prevent this problem but I'm intrigued why this call deadlocked. Basically I have a list of head objects and I need to load each ones details from a DB repository object (using Dapper). I attempted to do this using `ContinueWith` but it failed:

```
List<headObj> heads = await _repo.GetHeadObjects();
var detailTasks = heads.Select(s => _changeLogRepo.GetDetails(s.Id)
    .ContinueWith(c => new ChangeLogViewModel() {
         Head = s,
         Details = c.Result
 }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion));

await Task.WhenAll(detailTasks);

//deadlock here
return detailTasks.Select(s => s.Result);
```

**Can someone explain what caused this deadlock?** I tried to get my head round what has happened here but I'm not sure. I'm presuming it's something to do with calling `.Result` in the `ContinueWith`

### Additional information

- This is a webapi app called in an `async` context
- The repo calls are all along the lines of:

  ```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<ItemChangeLog>> GetDetails(int headId)
  {
      using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
      {
          return await connection.QueryAsync<ItemChangeLog>(@"SELECT [Id]
           ,[Description]
           ,[HeadId]
              FROM [dbo].[ItemChangeLog]
              WHERE HeadId = @headId", new { headId });
      }
  }
  ```
- I have since fixed this issue with the following code:

  ```
   List<headObj> heads = await _repo.GetHeadObjects();
   Dictionary<int, Task<IEnumerable<ItemChangeLog>>> tasks = new Dictionary<int, Task<IEnumerable<ItemChangeLog>>>();
   //get details for each head and build the vm
   foreach(ItemChangeHead head in heads)
   {
         tasks.Add(head.Id, _changeLogRepo.GetDetails(head.Id));
   }
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values);

   return heads.Select(s => new ChangeLogViewModel() {
          Head = s,
          Details = tasks[s.Id].Result
      });
  ```

Comment: Try changing `var detailTasks = heads.Select(...)` to `var detailTasks = heads.Select(...).ToList()`. If this is the case, this question might be a duplicate :)

Comment: Ah, ok, so it's a enumerable issue. Your right, that seems to make it run though @FCin. I'd still like a good explanation of the symantics here.

Comment: Let me find related question, but basically, because you are iterating over the same enumerable more than once, you actually create the same tasks multiple times. First when you do `await Task.WhenAll(...)`. Then when you do `detailTasks.Select(s => s.Result);` you wait for a completely new set of tasks.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm following that. The dupe sounds interesting, thanks @FCin

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861316/c-why-does-it-take-so-long-to-get-a-task-t-result-when-the-task-has-already-fi#comment90675145_51861316). You don't use `.ToArray`, but `Task.WhenAll` internally creates a list to avoid situation where someone edits items in enumerable while `Task.WhenAll` waits for it to finish. And to finally answer your question as to why it deadlocks: If I'm correct and asp.net web api has `SynchronizationContext`, then it deadlocks because you synchronously wait (`.Result`) for unfinished tasks on `SynchronizationContext` Thread.

Comment: I think it's probably worth an answer @FCin, that doesn't seem quite a duplicate. I'm pretty sure your right and that comment makes sense. If you could put all that into an answer I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Webapi does have `SynchronizationContext`  BTW so your right there too

Comment: I will post it as an answer once I get back home. It is a good lesson to use lists/arrays instead of enumerable when working with tasks.

Comment: Yes, not something I was really aware of. Thanks

Comment: @FCin - Well, specifically with enumerables that create new tasks within their definitions. If you end up with an enumerable of tasks but it's sourcing all of it's tasks from pre-existing ones, there's no issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is actually a combination of the above.  An enumeration of tasks was created where each time the enumeration is iterated, a fresh `GetDetails` call.  A `ToList` call on this Select would fix the deadlock.  Without solidifying the results of the enumerable (putting them in a list), the `WhenAll` call evaluates the enumerable and waits for the resulting tasks asynchronously without issue, but when the returned Select statement evaluates, it's iterating and synchronously waiting on the results of tasks resulting from fresh `GetDetails` and `ContinueWith` calls that have not yet completed.  All of this synchronous waiting is likely occurring while trying to serialize the response.

As to why that synchronous wait causes a deadlock, the mystery is in how await does things.  It completely depends on what you're calling.  An await is actually just retrieval of an awaiter via any scope-visible qualifying `GetAwaiter` method and registration of a callback that immediately calls `GetResult` on the awaiter when the work is complete.  A qualifying `GetAwaiter` method can be an instance or extension method that returns an object having an `IsCompleted` property, a parameterless `GetResult` method (any return type, including void - result of await), and either `INotifyCompletion` or `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` interfaces.  The interfaces both have `OnComplete` methods to register the callback.  There's a mind-boggling chain of `ContinueWith` and await calls going on here and much of it depends on the runtime environment.  The default behavior of the await you get from a `Task<T>` is to use `SynchronizationContext.Current` (I think via `TaskScheduler.Current`) to invoke the callback or, if that's null to use the thread pool (I think via `TaskScheduler.Default`) to invoke the callback.  A method containing an await gets wrapped as a Task by some `CompilerServices` class (forgot the name), giving callers of the method the above described behaviour wrapping whatever implementation you are awaiting.

A `SynchronizationContext` can also customize this, but typically each context invokes on it's own single thread.  If such an implementation is present on `SynchronizationContext.Current` when `await` is called on a `Task`, and you synchronously wait for the `Result` (which itself is contingent on an invoke to the waiting thread), you get a deadlock.

On the other hand, if you broke your as-is method out to another thread, or call `ConfigureAwait` on any of the tasks, or hide the current scheduler for your `ContinueWith` calls, or set your own `SynchronizationContext.Current` (not recommended), you change all the above.